# Spring MVC with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

*I have a situation like where i need to add list of object (in JS)*, I need to add these object in DB , for this i have a angular service takes list of object to call Spring Rest Controller to add these list of object to DB. I need to Synchronize my view with the controller. i.e as soon as objects are getting saved in DB , *I need to show that this Object name added in DB while the process is for adding other is in progress. This needs to be done in signal call*.

Comment: Is there any API that Spring provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two functions in service/factory of the angular f/w and then call the two functions one after the other in the controller just after the save button click event

Please let me know if you need some more information

Thank you

Comment: I have a situation like when a Rest controller is triggered for doing some long running operation asynchronously, then at the same time i need to show how much processing has been done.Since asynchronous Rest controller will return once completion in done in future ,then i can i get intermediate result from this asynchronous rest controller before returning final result.

Comment: since you want to show the intermediate result , which is nothing but the

Comment: sorry i continued here   which is nothing but the showing of the progress bar  so you can have the progress bar in the ui where this event is connected to a if condition if the http request is not completed  or not using if($http.pendingRequests.length > 0)   then your progress bar still shows the progress status